# Неправильно определяет текущую дату при выводе в .doc файл

Tags: дата, magento

Есть аукцион на Magento 1.9.1.1. В нем после окончания торгов формируется .doc файл с протоколом торгов по html шаблону. Текущее время выводится в ячейку таблицы с помощью `{{generated_date}}`. 
Это значение получает с кода:

```
$generatedDate = $productModel->getData('auction_date');
$generatedDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace("00:00:00", $productModel->getData('auction_time_to') . ":00", $generatedDate)));
if(strtotime($generatedDate) - Mage::getModel("core/date")->timestamp($bet->getCreatedAt()) < 60 * 5) {
$prolongation = (int) ($productModel->getData('prolongation') ? $productModel->getData('prolongation') : 10);
$generatedDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($bet->getCreatedAt()) + (60 * $prolongation));
}
$generatedDate = new Zend_Date($generatedDate, null, Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocale());
 $generatedDateStr = $_coreHelper->formatDate($generatedDate, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_LONG);
 $generatedDateStr .= ' ' . $_coreHelper->formatTime($generatedDate, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
$content = str_replace('{{generated_date}}', $generatedDateStr, $content);
```

И вот дата что выводиться на 2 часа раньше чем нужно. Хотя в magento везде указан часовой пояс "Киев". Как в эту переменную записать реальное текущее значение или к этому добавить 2 часа?

Comment: а часовой пояс в ОС и базе данных какой?

Comment: На сервере какой часовой пояс?

Comment: Киевский !!!!!!